# Automatically refresh table generated by knockout.js for each binding after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I'm updating a table with the knockout.js for each binding based on an array. The array is created by connecting to a database via ajax and returning the notes. I also have a function very similar to GetNotes that is AddNotes and it allows the user to add a note to the notebook via another ajax call. How can I get the table to refresh automatically after a note is added preferably via ajax so the whole page does not have to reload?

View:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: NoteArray" >
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Note"></td>
```

ViewModel:

```
self.Notebook.subscribe(function () {
    var notes = GetNotes(x);
    self.NoteArray(notes);
};
```

API:

```
function GetNotes(notebook) {
    var response = $.ajax({
        //ajax request returning a list of notes
    }).responseText;

    var notes = response.d;

    return(notes);
 }; 

function AddNote(notebook) {
    $.ajax({
        //ajax request adding note
    });

 };
```

Comment: When you say 'get the table to refresh' are you looking at add the added note to your array or refresh all notes?

Comment: The note is added to the array, but I currently have to refresh the page completely before I see the note in the table. I would like to add the array and it automatically appear in the table.

Comment: The note is probably only added to your back-end array, not to your actual observableArray in your view model.  Just call myObservableArray.push(newNote) to add the new note

Comment: This works to add the array. My new problem is, my ajax call doesn't return an array, it simply sends data to a function in my code behind file that adds the data to the database . . . so i'm trying to push something that does not exist

Comment: I added an answer that should show you what I am implying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view model should contain the functions that are specific to that view.

```
function viewModel() {
    self.Notebook = ko.observableArray();
    self.Notebook.subscribe(function () {
        var notes = self.getNotes(x);
        self.NoteArray(notes);
    };
    self.getNotes(x) {
        return GetNotes(x);
    }
    self.addNote(note) {
        self.NoteArray.push(note);
        return AddNote(note);
    }
}

function GetNotes(notebook) {
    var response = $.ajax({
        //ajax request returning a list of notes
    }).responseText;

    var notes = response.d;

    return(notes);
 }; 

function AddNote(notebook) {
    $.ajax({
        //ajax request adding note
    });    
};
```

I'm not sure exactly how you are calling addNote but since you need to add the note to the observableArray that exists in the current view model something along those lines should accomplish what you are trying to do.